# "Does .. have to" and "have .."?

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Are there equally grammatically correct:

- Does it have to be like it?
- Has it to be like it?

And

- Do you have a bottle of wine?
- Have you a bottle of wine?

Note that I haven't used used "got" because the question isn't about it.

Is it at least gramatically not incorrect  to use "have" as the main verb in a question, instead of "do"?

I mean primarily British English, written style.

Comment: As this is a fairly basic case: have you checked your grammar book/website and what do they say?

Comment: @Stephie yes. They've said: "do a research". And this is what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forming questions by inverstion with "has" is mandatory when "has" is an auxiliary verb:

> He has eaten the apple → Has he eaten the apple.

It is understandable but considered dated or archaic when "has" is the main verb.

> He has a ball → Has he a ball? (* dated, marked, odd)
> He has a ball → Does he have a ball? (* normal, plain)

So "Have you a bottle of wine?" is correct grammar, but marked and dated in British English.

English speakers would need to have a reason to use this construction.  "Because I can" is not enough.  "Because I need it for the poetry to scan" is a good reason.

Comment: Very marked and dated in American English too.  I always thought of it as more of a British thing, but maybe my information is dated!

Comment: Probably more common in BrE.  For AmE I think "Have you a ball" is simply a grammar error.

Comment: `English speakers would need to have a reason to use this construction.  "Because I can" is not enough.` - who will I have to provide that reason to? Am I obliged? In a written form? Verified by notary?

Comment: ha ha! of course not!  You are free to speak as oddly as you want and nobody can stop you.  Please enjoy.